# How come HTML can support <a/href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

Tags: html, dom

I just got to know that I can use  tag like:
`<a/href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

I have not read this thing ever in my career, might be, I have limited knowledge however it is creating some problem for me, because I am matching "`<a href`" in content and processing accordingly like making it open in new tab etc.

I tested it on browsers Chrome, Firefox and both allow it to be a link.

Is this standardized?

Comment: It's a hyperlink that takes you to google.com when clicked, aside from the extra / at the start, what is the question here ?

Comment: try this `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: You are right, however I am able to make link using <a/href also, which breaks some of My scrips like finding text in <a href

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't standard. It is an error. Browsers are very good at error recovery.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a syntactic markup error. Modern browsers will correct this, but older ones may show an error / cause the element to misbehave. If you run the page through a HTML [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

just add protocol **http://** before the link
and
add **target="_blanck"** for new tab

```html
 
 
 <a href="http://www.twitter.com/MomoAmoory" target="_blanck" type="button">Follow</a>
 
 </br></br>
 
   <a href="http://www.instagram.com/MomoAmoory" target="_blanck"  type="button">Follow</a>
   </br></br>
   
    <a  href="tel:+966500000000" type="button">call us</a>
```